# Mybatis - Invalid bound statement (not found): nutri.api.infrastructure.datasource.ClientMapper.getClientById

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix this issue.

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement
> (not found):
> nutri.api.infrastructure.datasource.ClientMapper.getClientById

My mapper interface and mapper XML file exist in the same directory and it has the same name.
I searched for similar cases but nothing helped me to solve it. I'm using Gradle building tool.

Here are my codes...

ClientApiController

```
@RestController
public class ClientApiController {

    @Autowired
    ClientService clientService;

    @GetMapping("/client/{id}")
    public Client get(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        return clientService.getClientById(id);
    }
}
```

ClientService

```
@Service
public class ClientService {

    ClientRepository clientRepository;

    public ClientService(ClientRepository clientRepository) {
       this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
    }

    public Client getClientById(int id) {
        Client client = clientRepository.getClientById(id);
        return client;
    }
}
```

ClientRepository

```
public interface ClientRepository {
    Client getClientById(int id);
}
```

ClientDatasource

```
@Repository
public class ClientDatasource implements ClientRepository {

    ClientMapper clientMapper;

    public ClientDatasource(ClientMapper clientMapper) {
        this.clientMapper = clientMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Client getClientById(int id) {
        Client client = clientMapper.getClientById(id);
        return client;
    }
}
```

ClientMapper

```
@Mapper
public interface ClientMapper {
    Client getClientById(int id);
}
```

ClientMapper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="nutri.api.infrastructure.datasource.ClientMapper">

    <resultMap id="resultClient" type="nutri.api.domain.model.Client">
        <result property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="clientNumber" column="client_number"/>
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
        <result property="email" column="email"/>
        <result property="healthCondition" column="health_condition"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getClientById" parameterType="int" resultMap="resultClient">
        SELECT
            id,
            client_number,
            name,
            email,
            health_condition
        FROM
            client.data
        WHERE
            id = #{id}
    </select>
</mapper>
```

And here is my Gradle configuration(gradle.build)

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "java-library"
}

sourceCompatibility = '15'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.1.4'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.18'
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2"
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'

    runtime project(':database')

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Comment: I really need help with this matter because I've been trying to solve it for two days and nothing is working so far.

Comment: Is it the SpringBoot framework?

Comment: @HaiZi Yes, this is Spring Boot. I'm using java 15

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this issue??

Comment: Can you upload the code to github? I’ll take a look after get off work and remember to give the access address

Comment: @HaiZi here is my project on github https://github.com/nnakamura95/nutri/tree/develop

Comment: I did not find this problem after I deployed your project to my local 
      http://image.haicheng.website/20210124144547.png

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the mapper interface corresponding to namespace in the xml file exists
[image]
Secondly, check whether the configuration file has the following configuration information for Mybatis：

```xml
# xml file location
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath*:/mapper/*.xml
# The location of the entity class
mybatis.type-aliases-package=website.lhc.sealadmin.model
```

Comment: I don't think this would make any difference? Because my mapper interface and mapper xml exist in the same directory and both of the files have the same name. Additionally, yes, inside the spacename has the corresponding mapper interface.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound crazy, but I resolved it by adding a space before the resulttype

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).